# Update object on PUT request using web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

In my web api, the PUT request is data bound using an interface like this `public void Put([FromBody] IPage value)`, this works great but what is the best approach to update the object and put it back into my storage? Note that I'm using an interface here and the correct type is posted within the json using the `$type` attribute.

I'm also using RavenDB so putting the value straight into the document store does not work because the posted object is not associated with the current session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcus,

Why can't you just call `session.Store(value);` ?

Comment: RavenDB throws an exception when I'm doing so, not associated with the session. I only tested this via fiddler but I guess it would act the same if the `PUT` came from the page. But, as far as you know, it should work?

Comment: Actually that worked great, the problem was that I had some other code that interfered with the request and loaded the exact same object I tried to store, with that said, thanks @ayende-rahien